# Helper of TextInputLayout is not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

As in title - even though I have helper set to my TextInputLayout it don't appears. I checked it on emulator. Why it is like that?

Code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
        style="@style/TextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/text_input_layout_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"
        app:helperText="@string/password_length"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/emailLayout"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
            style="@style/TextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            tools:text="" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Styles.xml:

```
    <style name="TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="strokeColor">@drawable/text_input_stroke_color</item>
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">?textAppearanceNavButton</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorTextInput</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextInputEditText" parent="Widget.Material3.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?textAppearanceInput</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextInput</item>
    </style>
```

Design view:

[image: Design View]

Comment: Try setting the _TextInputLayout_ height to `wrap_content`. I think that you are truncating the helper text by specifying a height.

Comment: Thank you @Cheticamp ! That was the problem in this case.